# Interpretation of expected value of a Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability

I was wondering if there was a simple explanation for what the expected value of a geometric distribution means. Solving for it is pretty simple $\dfrac{1}{p}$ or $\dfrac{1-p}{p}$  but what does it describe? Also what can the standard deviation of the geometric distribution be used for, or what can you calculate with it?

Comment: Expected value is average number of trials til first success.  What are you asking?  Standard deviations (in general)  are used to estimate the range of true values.  You need to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a relationship between the standard deviation of a geometric distribution and its mean/expected value. Like with a normal distribution, 68% of observations are within 1 standard deviations from the mean, 95% are within 2 standard deviations ect. Is there a similar rule with a geometric distribution? If not is there some other useful measure you can find with the standard deviation?

Comment: I am not aware of any particular rule for geometric distribution.  In general statisticians use the normal distribution rules.